# Make ripple fill whole View

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, ripple, rippledrawable

In my application I want to create a ripple which fills the whole view. Because it doesn't worked properly I created a minimal example app and tried it there but with no success.

My Layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="16dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:onClick="onViewClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my drawable is defined like this:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#1E88E5"
    android:radius="0dp">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</ripple>
```

[Here](https://youtu.be/nBWlNkrkeHE) is a video how it looks currently. I want that the circle (I think its called hotspot officially) grows from the middel until it fills the whole `View`. I'm not talking about the radius of the ripple which is consciously set to 0dp here. Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this?

**EDIT:** In the end I want to achieve something like [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0B4kv-3uZbS1qN21uRzN6OF9KQ00/useredu-er-featuredisc-motion-idle2.mp4).

*For everyone who do not want to read all the answers: I managed to implement it and create a [repo](https://github.com/Cilenco/WholeRippleView) for this. Fell free to use this in your project and send me pull requests.*

Comment: Which API do you have on the actual REAL test device? Unfortunately I think it (RippleDrawable) only works on API 21+ (Android 5.0, LOLLIPOP). support library 21 still won't make it work on older devices.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I tested it on API 26 Oreo. Would be great if the real solution works on API 14+

Comment: I think I've seen a library that can do that, get back to you if I find it.

Comment: @Cilenco Try using this 
 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground".if u are ok with libraries check this out https://android-arsenal.com/tag/167

Comment: https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect library is the best I have tested. Easy to Implement and API 14 +.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by creating your custom RippleView. Draw circle on full view using `onDraw` method and set Animation to that circle.

```
if (animationRunning) {
            canvas.save();
            if (rippleDuration <= timer * frameRate) {
                animationRunning = false;
                timer = 0;
                durationEmpty = -1;
                timerEmpty = 0;
                // There is problem on Android M where canvas.restore() seems to be called automatically
                // For now, don't call canvas.restore() manually on Android M (API 23)
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != 23) {
                    canvas.restore();
                }
                invalidate();
                if (onCompletionListener != null) onCompletionListener.onComplete(this);
                return;
            } else
                canvasHandler.postDelayed(runnable, frameRate);

            if (timer == 0)
                canvas.save();


            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, (radiusMax * (((float) timer * frameRate) / rippleDuration)), paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff4444"));

            if (rippleType == 1 && originBitmap != null && (((float) timer * frameRate) / rippleDuration) > 0.4f) {
                if (durationEmpty == -1)
                    durationEmpty = rippleDuration - timer * frameRate;

                timerEmpty++;
                final Bitmap tmpBitmap = getCircleBitmap((int) ((radiusMax) * (((float) timerEmpty * frameRate) / (durationEmpty))));
                canvas.drawBitmap(tmpBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
                tmpBitmap.recycle();
            }

            paint.setColor(rippleColor);

            if (rippleType == 1) {
                if ((((float) timer * frameRate) / rippleDuration) > 0.6f)
                    paint.setAlpha((int) (rippleAlpha - ((rippleAlpha) * (((float) timerEmpty * frameRate) / (durationEmpty)))));
                else
                    paint.setAlpha(rippleAlpha);
            }
            else
                paint.setAlpha((int) (rippleAlpha - ((rippleAlpha) * (((float) timer * frameRate) / rippleDuration))));

            timer++;
        }
```

<sup>The implementation is stolen from [RippleEffect Library](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) project. Find full implementation in library project.</sup>

To create circle from only center poistion use below method

```
 /**
     * Launch Ripple animation for the current view centered at x and y position
     *
     * @param x Horizontal position of the ripple center
     * @param y Vertical position of the ripple center
     */
    public void animateRipple(final float x, final float y) {
        createAnimation(x, y);
    }



/**
 * Create Ripple animation centered at x, y
 *
 * @param x Horizontal position of the ripple center
 * @param y Vertical position of the ripple center
 */
private void createAnimation(final float x, final float y) {
    if (this.isEnabled() && !animationRunning) {
        if (hasToZoom)
            this.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);

        radiusMax = Math.max(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        if (rippleType != 2)
            radiusMax /= 2;

        radiusMax -= ripplePadding;

        if (isCentered || rippleType == 1) {
            this.x = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            this.y = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        } else {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        animationRunning = true;

        if (rippleType == 1 && originBitmap == null)
            originBitmap = getDrawingCache(true);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Output :

You can get circle that grows from the middle until it fills the whole View
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I managed to implement this by myself and created a [repo](https://github.com/Cilenco/WholeRippleView) for it. I used the Animation class from API 11 and do not calculate all by myself like in the library so decide by yourself which version is best suited for you.

Answer (score 2):

### Ripple effect For Clickable Views

```
ripple effect for regular buttons will work by default in API 21, and for other
touchable views it can be achieved by specifying

    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

In Java CODE 

    int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
    TypedArray typedArray = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
    myView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
```

**Buttons** 

[image: Button Image]

```
Most buttons are made with several drawables. Usually you’ll have a pressed and
normal version of assets like this:

/drawable/button.xml:
```

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

```
If you have a custom button with selected state, your text color changes 
depending on the state, etc. So the default button background is not going 
to work for you here. You can add this feedback for your own drawables and 
for custom buttons by simply wrapping them in a ripple element:

/drawable-v21/button.xml:
```

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</ripple>
```

**Using `?android:colorControlHighlight` will give the ripple the same color as the built-in ripples in your app.**

**If you don’t like the default grey, you can specify what color you want `android:colorControlHighlight` to be in your theme.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/your_custom_color</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**If you want the ripple to extend past the boundary of the view, then you can 
instead use `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`. This works well with 
ImageButtons and smaller Buttons that are part of a larger View:**

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope its work for you

**Use** `android:foreground="@drawable/ripple"`

**instead of** `android:background="@drawable/ripple"`

and also change `android:radius="0dp"` to 50dp or 100dp and check